# Cast Object[] to Type[] via Reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, reflection, setvalue

**Goal**

I have an object[]Source,object Target, and FieldInfo Var (Var.FieldType.IsArray is true).
I want to run Var.SetValue(Target,Source). 
However, I cannot convert "object[]" -> "anotherType[]"

**Sample Run**

```
object[]Source=new object[2]{"Hello","World"};
Var.SetValue(Target,Source); //Cannot Convert "object[]"->"string[]"
```

[note: I want to be able to use ints, doubles, floats, etc. Otherwise, this problem would be trivially easy]

**Research**

*Use Var:* 
Cannot use because cannot create var arrays

*Use Generics:*

This works for

```
myField.SetValue(target,GenericCastArray<string>(source));
```

However, it does not work for

```
Type someType=typeof(string); //or int, or float
 (myfield.SetValue(target,GenericCastArray< someType > (source))
```

*
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/fe14d396-bc35-4f98-851d-ce3c8663cd79/* returns null reference exception, I think at this.GetType()

**EDIT: Meh Solution**
Based on the comments, it is impossible to convert from object[] to string[].
However, the following code works adequately well.

```
object[]Source=null;
Type basetype=Var.FieldType.GetElementType();
int l=somelength;
if (basetype.IsEquivalentTo(typeof(string))) Source = new string[l];
//repeat for all types

source=//run your Reflection here

var.SetValue(target,source);
```

Comment: Is there any reason the source needs to be object[]? Is there no way you could make the source generic and therefore not need to do a cast? Can you explain what you are using for this? You can do generic casts in a generic class, so it may be something like that is what you want...

Comment: Frankly what you're trying to do won't work.  You can only use generics if you know enough about the type at compile time.  You clearly don't know what type you're given until runtime (through `someType`).

Comment: @Charleh I am trying to use Reflection to serialize arrays of strings/ints/doubles/etc. Thanks for the suggestion regarding making Source generic, though I'm a bit puzzled on how to do this. I will research on this.

Comment: What is the signature of `SetValue()`?  You can use reflection here, but that's a whole different beast.

Comment: Can you go into detail and maybe post what you are trying to serialize, why you are trying to do it, what object you are serializing from, what object you are trying to deserialize to and maybe put some of the code up. Usually using reflection for something like this means you are probably not going about it the right way

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks. I was thinking that might be the case. In this case, I don't think Charleh's answer would work either, right?

Comment: @Charleh  I will edit my post with details

Comment: Serializing an object should allow the object to be recovered at the other end of whatever communication channel you serialized via. How are you serializing? Have you marked the object serializable? Are you using XmlSerializer or BinaryFormatter? What network method are you using to transmit? Are you using sockets? UDP? TCP?

Comment: It looks like you aren't using the built-in serialization methods in .NET? Seeing as you are using reflection to discover field information, you might as well use the .NET serializers.. is that not something you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for all the help Charleh. I have zero experience with framework Serializers. I'm using an external library, which handles seriailization extremely well. I've opted for an undramatic meh solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to cast Array of one type to Array of another type (i.e. `object[]` to `string[]`) because these are different non compatible types. Reflection will not help to cast either.

To convert you will always need to create some sort of copy of the array either directly or by creating `IEnumerable<DestinationType>` via one of LINQ conversion functions.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. You can cast e.g. `string[]` to `object[]` thanks to array covariance. (Although array covariance is a bad idea and .Net has it only because it wanted to be compatible with Java.)

Comment: ... and array covariance only works between arrays of reference types.  It does not work for arrays of value types at all.